# AWS Organization not using Consolidated Billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-organizations, aws-billing

In AWS I have configured Organizations, but at the end of the month I receive separate invoices for every member account, and I need to pay them separately.

How I can make one invoice for all the needed payments in my Organization?

Here is an example:

[image: separate member account invoices]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive separate bills at the end of the month, that means that you need to activate tax settings inheritance.

You can find it in Billing Dashboard -> Tax settings:

[image: Example]

Note: This information is provided from AWS Support